# Does the Emulator of Android Studio support in-app android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, in-app-purchase

I have a android app with in-app purchases, it works well in my real phone.

I create a virtual device with API Level 22 and Target of Google APIs. When I test the app in the virtual device, I get the following error:

```
Problem setting up in-app billing:An error occurred when initialize billing!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android emulator does not support In App Purchases.

See the official documentation for more information:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html